# How to solve signal MFSK or FHSS question (received signal+ noise+jamming)

Tags: frequency-spectrum, fsk, spread-spectrum

I'm trying to solve the following: 
\begin{equation}
A \cos(2\pi f t + \theta_1) + B \cos(2\pi f t + \theta_2) = D\cos(?f?\theta)
\end{equation}

I just need to know the correct value of D, the value of frequency and delta is not important since it is non-coherent.

Comment: [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities) Search for "arbitrary phase shift"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A\cos(2\pi f+\theta_1)+B\cos(2\pi f+\theta_2)=C\cos(2\pi f+\theta_3)$$

where

$$C=|u|\quad\textrm{and}\quad \theta_3=\arg\{u\}$$

with

$$u=Ae^{j\theta_1}+Be^{j\theta_2}$$

The constant $C$ can be written as

$$C=\sqrt{A^2+2AB\cos(\theta_1-\theta_2)+B^2}$$